# How to send data from client to only socket server

Tags: node.js, socket.io, socket.io-redis, engine.io

I know that if I emit data on a socket, the data would be emitted to the all connected clients.

`io.emit("test", data)`

For instance if I run the command above, actually the data reaches to the all clients. But only `test` channel listeners handle it.

To prevent that, I use rooms. I use code like the following:

`io.in("test").emit(data)`

So, what if a client send data to the server, then will data be reached to the all clients?

Note: I also use `socket.io-redis` to make cluster.

Answer (score 0):

This code will send to all client in "roomName"

`io.to(roomName).emit('new msg', {data:'hello every clients'});`